# Run docker command on host

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-container

Can I run docker command on host? I installed `aws` inside my docker container, now can I somehow use `aws` command on host (that under the hood will use docker container's aws)?

My situation is like that: I have database backups on production host. now I have Jenkins cron job that will take sql file from db container and take it into server folder. Now I also want jenkins to upload this backup file on AWS storage, but on host I have no aws installed, also I don't want to install anything except docker on my host, so I think aws should be installed inside container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly do this.  Docker containers and images have isolated filesystems, and the host and containers can't directly access each others' filesystems and binaries.

In theory you could write a shell script that wrapped `docker run`, name it `aws`, and put it in your `$PATH`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec docker run --rm -it awscli aws "$@"
```

but this doesn't scale well, requires you to have root-level permissions on the host, and you won't be able to access files on the host (like `~/.aws/config`) or environment variables (like `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`) with additional setup.

You can just install software on your host instead, and it will work normally.  There's no requirement to use Docker for absolutely everything.

Answer (score 0):

Since the docker host is a server with users you can execute commands remotely on the host via `ssh` from the container. Example:

```
docker_hostname="my-host"
docker_host_user="jimmyneutron"
ssh $docker_host_user@$docker_hostname 'echo $HOSTNAME' # returns: my-host
```

Now you can also execute a docker command from a container as if you are on the host. Example:

```
ssh $docker_host_user@$docker_hostname "docker exec myOtherContainer sh -c 'aws ...'
```

If needed you can setup public key based authentication for passwordless ssh access on the host. See https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/